# How can I add cell line style

Tags: phpword

How can I add cell line style
Frame style

[image]

```html
//創建一個table
$table = $section -> addTable($fancyTableStyleName);
$headTitleNum = array('valign' => 'center','borderSize' => 5,'bgColor' => 'a1ffdb');
$table -> addRow();
$table -> addCell(2100,$headTitleNum) -> addText("");
$table -> addCell(2000,$headTitleNum) -> addText("");
$table -> addCell(1900,$headTitleNum) -> addText("");
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far and how it failed. You might also be interested in learning [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

```html
$fancyTableStyleName = 'Ranking Table';
$fancyTableStyle = array('borderSize' => 5,'borderColor' => '404040','cellSpacing' => 7, 'cellMargin' => 20, 'alignment' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\SimpleType\JcTable::CENTER);
```